# Provision to mark old answers with old technology

Tags: discussion, feature-request

It is likely that same problem can be faced by many programmers from time to time.

However, the solution changes depending on the available technology.

For example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887036) problem has a lot of replies those are correct but the replies with mysql functions are not correct if you are using PHP 7 or higher, correct for lower versions. PHP has lots of such deprecated functions. I don't know about other languages but my experience says there must be.

These replies should get not removed as they are correct at the time of replying. If someone facing problem, after not getting the suitable reply, will ask the same question but that will get a duplicate tag and down vote. (Downvote matters as it's linked with privileges to use the site)

Should we add an option to flag the reply, as 'Old way of doing' so that the one who is looking for that solution can get an idea how to proceed and where to get the new equivalent.

In case of outdated questions, we can move the question to a separate section or mark it as an outdated problem.

Comment: Aren't comments and downvotes sufficient for this?

Comment: @yannis I have mentioned the problem with downvote. Moreover why to  downvote a reply which was correct at the time of replying. Comments make sense but in some cases, the no of comments go so long that after you have gone through a lot of trials, troubleshooting and finally found that the feature is no longer available. You may argue that one must know about the functions of the language one is using but you can't deny how frustrating things become when you spend hours just for a single feature.

Comment: I saw your comment to that (terrible) answer there and you did the correct thing - You added a comment for future users to ignore it. It will be impossible to manage this operation you're suggesting because features in PHP7 will also be deprecated  in future

Comment: @NewBee You also have the option of editing the answer to let people know that the proposed solution is outdated.

Comment: @AlonEitan We can have a feature to mark these replies/questions, sort of abondaning. Its true old features will get deprecated and new ones will come up but it's less likely that any deprecated feature will be made available in future.

Comment: @yannis yes, but why to interfare with someone's answer which is correct. I, rather no one should have that authority. Don't you think it's sort of breaking the law.

Comment: @AlonEitan Sorry mine is duplicate. Didn't search with 'deprecate' so couldn't find that. Please close this discussion.

Comment: This is a collaboratively edited site, improving other people's posts is encouraged. See [Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) for more details.

Comment: @yannis Thanks. It's nice that the site is not that strict on such issues. Honestly speaking I'm from electrical engineering background. I have designed and maintain a site just for hobby. Google brings me here when I try to work on that site so I haven't gone through its every page, hence missed. Sorry for the trouble. Better I stay silent.

Comment: @NewBee No need to be sorry :) It is only natural to hesitate before editing a post that has a prominent user card at the bottom, but that is indeed par for the course here: here we have individual post authorship and collaborative editing at the same time.